# Unpack zip archives parallel in Ansible to speedup playbook execution failed: "async is not supported for this task."

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, ansible, unzip

I have a playbook that should download and extract multiple zip files. Those archives are several hundred MB up to multiple GB huge, so both steps take some time. I'd like to improve the performance with async operations:

```
- name: Downloading cnx 6.5 files from flexnet
  become: yes
  flexnet_download:
    user: "{{ flexnet_download.user }}"
    password: "{{ flexnet_download.password }}"
    target: "{{ flexnet_download.target }}/cnx"
    package_id: HCL_Connections_6.5_CRx
    files:
      - HCL_Connections_6.5_lin.tar

- name: Downloading db2 files from flexnet
  become: yes
  async: 3600 #1h
  poll: 0
  flexnet_download:
    user: "{{ flexnet_download.user }}"
    password: "{{ flexnet_download.password }}"
    target: "{{ flexnet_download.target }}/db2"
    package_id: HCL_Connections_6.5
    files:
      - CNB75ML.tar
      - CNB23ML.zip

- name: "Unpack cnx installer archive {{ cnx.install_archive_core }} to {{ cnx.install_dir_core }}"
  become: yes
  async: 3600 #1h
  poll: 0
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ cnx.install_archive_core }}"
    dest: "{{ cnx.install_dir_core }}"
    creates: "{{ cnx.install_dir_core }}/launchpad.sh"
    extra_opts:
      - --strip=1
```

The first task downloads the first zip. Then I try to download the other zips in parallel while extracting the first zip (`cnx.install_archive_core` is the full path to `HC6.5_CR1.zip`). Sadly the `unarchive` task failed:

```
TASK [Unpack cnx installer archive /opt/cnx-install/cnx/HCL_Connections_6.5_lin.tar to /opt/cnx-install/cnx/core] **********************************************************************************
Saturday 06 February 2021  12:45:19 +0000 (0:02:39.856)       0:02:40.551 *****
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: async is not supported for this task.
```

I guess the `unarchive` module doesn't support. But I'm wondering that there seems no documentation [in the `unarchive` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html) about it. Since Ansible is luckily open source, I [found this check](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-bare/blob/e0a7c04875165ac6c1b54367bc5b84c9f41e9d6e/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L100) where it seem sthat the module need to set a property `_supports_async = True` to allow async usage. When [searching for async plugins](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=self._supports_async+%3D+True), I just found 8 plugins - none of them could be used for extracting.

### Is there any alternative to unpack archives async?

Or what must be done to add async support to the `unarchive` module? I guess async is realized by [running tasks in the background](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/) and then polling stdout/stderr in the specified interval.

### What do I need to consider when extracting using the `unzip` CLI tool this way?

I know this is not the prefered *Ansible way* of doing things. But the only way I see is to run `unzip` manually on the shell, the [`command` plugin supports async](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/a077bca5d5866603cdc4a2a13aef8f416860aacb/lib/ansible/plugins/action/command.py#L15).

Answer (score -1):

So it's been almost 3 years and `unarchive` module still does not support async mode.

But there still are some ways to trick Ansible.

### Use inventories to run the same tasks on the same machine with different variables in parallel

Instead of running two (or more) tasks asynchronously, we can just connect to the same target host twice (or more) and run them as usual. Because Ansible runs the plays in parallel.

We should adjust our inventory - define two hosts that will have different values for the parameters of the downloads and target directories:

```yaml
---
downloads:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local # it could be of any type
    ansible_host: localhost # also any - the idea is that it's the same machine for both host names in inventory
    install_archive_core: "./archive/Archive-{{ inventory_hostname }}.zip" 
    install_dir_core: "unarchived/{{ inventory_hostname }}" # `cnx` or `db2` is used to separate the paths
  hosts:
    cnx:
      package_id: HCL_Connections_6.5_CRx
      files:
        - HCL_Connections_6.5_lin.tar
    db2:
      package_id: HCL_Connections_6.5
      files:
        - CNB75ML.tar
        - CNB23ML.zip
```

Sample playbook (surely simplified for testing):

```yaml
- name: Test async unpacking
  hosts: downloads
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Create the target directories
      file:
        path: "{{ install_dir_core }}"
        state: directory

    - name: Unpack the archive
      unarchive:
        src: "{{ install_archive_core }}"
        dest: "{{ install_dir_core }}"
      when: not ansible_check_mode
```

Let's test it. I have two equal archives: `Archive-cnx.zip` and `Archive-db2.zip` (both are 207,4 MB).
It takes around 13.5 seconds to unpack one `db2` archive, and the same amount of time for `cnx`:

```bash
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --inventory inventory.yml --limit db2
```

```
PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
cnx                        : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Friday 29 December 2023  04:08:47 +0100 (0:00:13.492)       0:00:14.092 *******
=============================================================================== 
Unpack the archive ----------------------------------------------------- 13.49s
Create the target directories ------------------------------------------- 0.58s
```

And it takes only 20 seconds to unpack both archives in parallel:

```bash
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --inventory inventory.yml
```

```
PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
cnx                        : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
db2                        : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Friday 29 December 2023  04:12:06 +0100 (0:00:19.866)       0:00:20.532 ******* 
=============================================================================== 
Unpack the archive ----------------------------------------------------- 19.87s
Create the target directories ------------------------------------------- 0.65s
```

### Use strategies to disable the synchronization between the tasks running in parallel

Based on that, we can go further and achieve even more. Since we need to download the archives before unpacking them, and probably do other stuff, we can let the workflows for different files be independent so that they don't wait for each other. That's where [`strategy: free`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/free_strategy.html#free-strategy) can help: it does not block the execution of the subsequent tasks for other hosts of the current batch in a play:

```yaml
- name: Test async downloading and unpacking
  hosts: downloads
  gather_facts: false
  strategy: free
  tasks:
    - name: Downloading files from flexnet
      become: yes
      flexnet_download:
        user: "{{ flexnet_download.user }}"
        password: "{{ flexnet_download.password }}"
        target: "{{ install_archive_core }}"
        package_id: "{{ package_id }}"
        files: "{{ files }}"
      
    - name: Create the target directories
      file:
        path: "{{ install_dir_core }}"
        state: directory

    - name: Unpack the archive
      unarchive:
        src: "{{ install_archive_core }}"
        dest: "{{ install_dir_core }}"
      when: not ansible_check_mode
```

In this example, even if `Downloading files from flexnet` task takes longer for one of the files, Ansible will not wait for its finish, and will continue with `Create the target directories` and `Unpack the archive` tasks of `Test async downloading and unpacking` play as soon as possible. And we can still use `async` and define our own points of synchronization in further plays.

I explained this approach mentioning some other details in a bit different context here: [Ansible Playbook run some hosts parallel and some serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711717/ansible-playbook-run-some-hosts-parallel-and-some-serial/77715537#77715537).