# Ansible Playbook run some hosts parallel and some serial

Tags: ansible

I want to run the same tasks on some hosts in parallel and on others in serial.

My playbook right now:

```yaml
---
- hosts: VMs
  gather_facts: false
  throttle: 1
  tasks:
  - name: apt update
    apt:
      update_cache: yes

- hosts: Server
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: apt update
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
```

So hosts `VMs` run one after another and when they are finished hosts `Server` run. But `Server` should run in parallel to `VMs`.
I tried and googled a lot, but cant't get what I want to happen.

The only "solution" was to run two playbooks at one time. But that is not what I want to do. If possible I want to have it in one playbook.

Comment: Did you look at async? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html

Comment: It's not possible to have it in one playbook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`async`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html), but in order to not block the subsequent tasks you will have to set [`poll: 0`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0) for the tasks that should be run concurrently. Also, you can use [`serial`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) keyword to control the size of the batch on play level:

```yaml
---
- hosts: Server
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: apt update (Server)
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
    async: 3600
    poll: 0
    register: server_task_result # if you need to poll it later

- hosts: VMs
  serial: 1 
  tasks:
  - name: apt update (VMs)
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
```

Note that Ansible will not wait for the asynchronous task to finish. If you need to run other tasks on `Server` group afterwards, save the execution result and poll for its `ansible_job_id` status later using [`async_status`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/async_status_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-async-status-module) module.

There is still another option - not elegant and actually kinda kludge, but potentially helpful if asynchronous mode is not supported by the module you need to run.

An interesting thing about `throttle` is that it [applies to a particular task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle). The [`strategy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html), however, applies to the play.
So you can try the [`free`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/free_strategy.html#free-strategy) strategy that does not block the execution of the subsequent tasks for other hosts of the batch. You will need to run both tasks within the single play, possibly rename your hosts so that [`order`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory) can guarantee that the hosts of `Server` group are first for the play to run on, and separate the `VMs` and `Server` groups:

```yaml
---
- hosts: VMs,Server
  gather_facts: false
  strategy: free
  order: sorted
  tasks:
  - name: apt update (Server)
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
    when:
      - inventory_hostname in groups['Server']

  - name: apt update (VMs)
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
    throttle: 1
    when: 
      - inventory_hostname in groups['VMs']
```