# Run multiple plays in parallel

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with two plays, I would like to for them to run in parallel, currently they are running in series.
Any advice?

Here is what the playbook currently looks like:

```yaml
---
- name: Install windows_hosts
  hosts: win
  tasks:
    # Windows specific tasks

- name: Install ubuntu_hosts
  hosts: ubu
  tasks:
    # Ubuntu specific tasks
  become: true
```

win and ubu have exactly 1 host in it, see hosts file below:

```yaml
win:
  hosts:
    win-host:
      ansible_host: <IP>
  vars:
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_winrm_transport: certificate
    ansible_winrm_user: ansible
    ansible_winrm_cert_pem: <CERT-PATH>
    ansible_winrm_cert_key_pem: <CERT-KEY-PATH>
    ansible_port: <PORT>
    ansible_winrm_scheme: https
    ansible_gather_timeout: 300
    ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 60
ubu:
  hosts:
    ubu-host:
      ansible_host: <IP>
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

I expect the two plays to run at the same time but it runs through all of the windows before it starts on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible runs tasks on hosts in parallel within a play, but the plays are always running subsequently.

So, generally the rules are as follows:

- you **can** run **the same tasks** in parallel **within the same play**;
- you **can't** run **different tasks** in parallel **within the same play**;
- you **can't** run **plays** in parallel, so you **can't** run **any tasks** in parallel **within different plays**.

If the tasks you want to run are supported on both Windows and Linux, you can just unite the groups like `hosts: win,ubu` and you're good - you don't need a second play.

If you're invoking some roles, the difference in target hosts operating systems may be processed in the role code using `when` [condition](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) - and you can do the same for your tasks, too. If you have lots of them, you can group them in a `block` so you have only two `when` conditions.

Also, there's a couple more tricks you could apply. They make use of `free` play execution [strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html), [asynchronous task execution](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html), and conditionals. I recommend to check out my answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077363/unpack-zip-archives-parallel-in-ansible-to-speedup-playbook-execution-failed-a/77730150#77730150) and [especially this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711717/ansible-playbook-run-some-hosts-parallel-and-some-serial/77715537#77715537) questions cause they are highly related in terms of possible solutions.

Remember that Ansible processes up to 5 hosts in parallel by default. You can change this behavior anytime via `ansible.cfg` file or the corresponding [`ANSIBLE_FORKS`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_FORKS) environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I went with, there was only a single diff between the plays so it ended up being fairly easy to combine them. See this comment for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828428/ansible-run-multiple-hosts-in-parallel/77828829#comment137207674_77828829

Answer (score 1):

There are more options:

1. Split the playbook into 2 playbooks and run them in parallel.
2. Put the OS-specific tasks into files and import them conditionally. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat win.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Windows specific tasks
```

```yaml
shell> cat ubu.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Ubuntu specific tasks
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - import_tasks: win.yml
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.win

    - import_tasks: ubu.yml
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.ubu
```

3. The play will be simpler if you can use [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html). See [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html)

- If the first 3 characters of the inventory hostnames are the OS acronyms

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: "{{ inventory_hostname[:3] }}.yml"
```

- If the names of the inventory groups are the OS acronyms and the hosts are not members of multiple groups. See the special variable [group_names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-group_names)

```yaml
- hosts: all
  
  tasks:

    - include_tasks: "{{ group_names.0 }}.yml"
```

- Create your mapping of tasks

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    os_tasks:
      win: win-tasks.yml
      ubu: ubu-tasks.yml

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: "{{ os_tasks[group_names.0] }}"
```

Comment: Thank you this helped, although I ended up going with a different approach. The tasks for windows and ubuntu were the same the only difference was the "become: true". I did some investigation and found that you can use become in windows but you have to alter the become method and user.

  become: true
  become_method: "{{ 'runas' if os_family == 'Windows' else 'sudo' }}"
  become_user: "{{ 'Administrator' if os_family == 'Windows' else 'root' }}"