Ansible - Windows - run multiple powershell processes asynchronsously with throttle limit
Goal
I have multiple Azure subscriptions (+200) where I need to run a powershell script to perform some work per subscription.
Working part
To speed up these runs, I have developed the following Ansible playbook that runs a powershell script in an asynchronous way on a specific host (so only 1 host).
I first thought I could use the keyword throttle for this, but it seems this limits the number of workers for a particular task, and I have only 1 worker (host).
So what I did is splitting up the list of subscriptions into batches of 9, and then for each batch, 9 powershell processes are run at the same time, using the async possibilities of Ansible.
I need to spin up a different powershell process for each subscription, because if I use powershell multithreading (or jobs), I have some weird errors coming from the fact the subscription scopes can 'leak' some data into other scopes when using multithreading.
(If you're interested, that issue is also described here).
Challenge
This works well, however, there is 1 big disadvantage: I need to wait until the last powershell process of that batch is finished, before the start of a new batch is done.
I'm looking for a way to start all subscriptions with a maximum of (i.e.) 9, and when 1 of the 9 is finished, the next process is started, and so forth.
Does someone has some experience in doing this?
Code
main.yml:
- name: Subscription list
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    all_subscriptions:
      - subscription1
      - subscription2
    [...]
      - subscription200

- name: Split subscriptions into batches
  vars:
    batch_size: 9
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    batches: "{{ all_subscriptions | batch(batch_size) }}"

- name: Process each batch
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: process_batch.yml
  loop: "{{ batches }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: batch_items

process_batch.yml:
- name: Execute PowerShell commands for batch
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', 'files/script.ps1') }}"
    executable: pwsh.exe
    error_action: stop
    parameters:
      SubscriptionData: "{{ subscription_item | to_json }}"
  async: 1500 # Allow each task up to 25 minutes to run
  poll: 0     # Do not wait for the task to finish; continue immediately
  register: async_jobs
  loop: "{{ batch_items }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: subscription_item

- name: Wait for all tasks in the batch to finish
  ansible.builtin.async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_status
  until: job_status.finished
  retries: 300
  loop: "{{ async_jobs.results }}"
  when: item.ansible_job_id is defined


You can trick Ansible into treating a single host as multiple ones with one subscription per host and take advantage of host-level parallelism where both throttle and serial would work as you initially expected - I described the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730150/16417367. There's also a link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77715537/16417367 which uses a similar approach.

Hello Alexander, thanks a lot for the feedback. That's an approach I didn't think of.
Using that approach, I think I need to use a static inventory file that defines a host per subscription.
However, I have simplified the list of subscriptions in my example as just a static list. In reality, this list is created using another playbook (using the powershell cmd search-azgraph). Do you think your approach is possible when the list of inventories is not static?

Yes it is, because you can create that list dynamically using something like add_host in a loop of your all_subscriptions.

Hello @AlexanderPletnev I have implemented this, and it works like a charm

Cool, glad it helped! I'll post it as an answer once I get more time.
